# Excel VBA throws next without for error, when there is for and next in the code

Tags: excel, vba

I am very new to excel VBA, I am prompted the error "Next without For" for the the below code, I donot understand why as I believe I got a for in the code

Thanks

```
    Dim failure() As Variant
    failure = Array("Fault Number", "Failure Number", "FAILURE_ID", "Fault No.", "FMS")
    Debug.Print failure(1)
    ' Get the range from the worksheet
    Dim rgSource As Range
    Dim i As Long
    
    For i = 0 To 5
     Set rgSource = wksource.Worksheets(1).Cells.Find(failure(i), SearchOrder:=xlRows)
     If rgSource <> 0 Then
     Exit For
     Else: Next i
     End If
```

I expect the code to run, I have tried debug.Print command to see whether array elements are correctly assigned

Answer (score 0):

You need to close your inner `If/Else` criteria, then close your `For/Next` outer loop.

Also, to trap Erros on `rgSource`, you need to use `If Not rgSource is Nothing`.

***Modified Code***

```
' objects and variables declaration
Dim failure() As Variant
Dim rgSource As Range
Dim i As Long

failure = Array("Fault Number", "Failure Number", "FAILURE_ID", "Fault No.", "FMS")
Debug.Print failure(1)

' loop through array
For i = LBound(failure) To UBound(failure)
    Set rgSource = wksource.Worksheets(1).Cells.Find(failure(i), SearchOrder:=xlRows)
    
    ' confirm Find was successful
    If Not rgSource Is Nothing Then
        Exit For
    Else
        ' do something ?
    End If
Next i
```

Comment: That worked thanks, what the grasp on the if not logic

Comment: @AravindDuppada you're welcome. Now comes your part where you mark the little check-mark next to my post as answer